# vitest Failed to load url using vite-tsconfig-paths

Tags: node.js, vite, tsconfig, vitest

I am trying to add vitest to my frontend, but have trouble setting up the paths.
The frontend runs fine when running `vite`, but for some reason custom paths fail when running `vitest`.

```
 FAIL  |front-admin| src/pages/admin/index.test.tsx [ frontend/apps/admin/src/pages/admin/index.test.tsx ]
Error: Failed to load url ~/schema (resolved id: ~/schema) in /..../frontend/apps/admin/src/pages/admin/Update.tsx. Does the file exist?
 ❯ loadAndTransform ../../../node_modules/vitest/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-R0I0XnyH.js:49376:21
```

I am using vite and vitest on an npm workspace, and my files look like this:
**vitest.workspace.ts**

```js
import { defineWorkspace } from 'vitest/config'
// @vitest-environment node
export default defineWorkspace([
  // you can use a list of glob patterns to define your workspaces
  // Vitest expects a list of config files
  // or directories where there is a config file
  'frontend/apps/*/vite.config.ts',
  // you can even run the same tests,
  // but with different configs in the same "vitest" process
  {
    test: {
      name: 'front-admin',
      root: './frontend/apps/admin',
      environment: 'node',
      setupFiles: ['./vitest.config.ts'],
    },
  },
  {
    test: {
      name: 'front-company',
      root: './frontend/apps/company',
      environment: 'node',
      setupFiles: ['./vitest.config.ts'],
    },
  },
])
```

**frontend/apps/admin/vite.config.ts**

```js
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), tsconfigPaths()],
  server: { port: 5173 },
  optimizeDeps: {
    exclude: ['prisma/factories'],
  },
})
```

**frontend/apps/admin/vitest.config.ts**

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config'

export default defineConfig({
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: 'node'
  },
})
```

**frontend/apps/admin/tsconfig.json**

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src", "index.html"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

**frontend/apps/admin/src/pages/Update.tsx**

```js
import { tokenInput } from '~/schema' // all other imports that rely on tsconfig fail as well
```

i tried adding and removing aliases from vite config, but it had no effect

```js
export default defineConfig({
  ...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '~/': path.join(__dirname, 'src/'),
    },
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if that is what caused the issue, but vitest.workspace.ts was testing the same repository twice.

```js
  // testing the first time
  'frontend/apps/*/vite.config.ts',

  // testing the second time
  {
    test: {
      name: 'front-admin',
      root: './frontend/apps/admin',
      environment: 'node',
      setupFiles: ['./vitest.config.ts'],
    },
  },
```

I didnt understand from the documentation, but the way the workspace file works is that you can either call a vitest file from vitest.workspace (first method), or directly set the settings from vitest.workspaces without having to create a vitest file in the root of the app.
**vitest.workspace.ts**

```js
import { defineWorkspace } from 'vitest/config'
// @vitest-environment node
export default defineWorkspace([
  // you can use a list of glob patterns to define your workspaces
  // Vitest expects a list of config files
  // or directories where there is a config file
  'frontend/apps/*/vitest.config.ts',
  // you can even run the same tests,
  // but with different configs in the same "vitest" process
  // test: { ... } is optional
])
```

**frontend/apps/admin/vitest.config.ts**

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config'

export default defineConfig({
  test: {
    globals: true,
    name: 'front-admin',
    root: './src',
    environment: 'happy-dom',
    setupFiles: ['./src/utils/vitest-setup.ts'],
  },
})
```